# Hono CLI start issue

Tags: command-line-interface, eclipse-hono

I recently deployed hono using Minikube. I followed the instructions, tunneled the cluster so it is available through localhost. I also successfully set up a tenant and I would like to test the MQTT Adapter with Mosquitto.

I tried to start the CLI to connect to the Northbound API as shown in the tutorial and I got the following error:

```
23:25:23.718 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.h.client.impl.HonoConnectionImpl - max number of attempts [5] to re-connect to server [127.0.0.1:15672, role: unknown] have been made, giving up
23:25:23.746 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] ERROR org.eclipse.hono.cli.app.Receiver - Error occurred during initialization of receiver: failed to connect
```

The command I tried to use:

```
java -jar hono-cli-*-exec.jar --hono.client.host=127.0.0.1 --hono.client.port=15672 --hono.client.username=consumer@HONO --hono.client.password=verysecret --tenant.id=$TENANT
```

I tried both 15672 and 15671 ports but none of them worked. Here is a log of the hono service:

```
NAME                                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                           AGE
eclipse-hono-adapter-amqp-vertx                 LoadBalancer   10.99.195.237    127.0.0.1     5672:32672/TCP,5671:32671/TCP     36h
eclipse-hono-adapter-http-vertx                 LoadBalancer   10.97.63.200     127.0.0.1     8080:30080/TCP,8443:30443/TCP     36h
eclipse-hono-adapter-mqtt-vertx                 LoadBalancer   10.100.216.206   127.0.0.1     1883:31883/TCP,8883:30883/TCP     36h
eclipse-hono-artemis                            ClusterIP      10.104.81.61     <none>        5671/TCP                          36h
eclipse-hono-dispatch-router                    ClusterIP      10.104.214.176   <none>        5673/TCP                          36h
eclipse-hono-dispatch-router-ext                LoadBalancer   10.100.97.6      127.0.0.1     15671:30671/TCP,15672:30672/TCP   36h
eclipse-hono-service-auth                       ClusterIP      10.99.59.114     <none>        5671/TCP                          36h
eclipse-hono-service-command-router             ClusterIP      10.104.190.85    <none>        5671/TCP                          36h
eclipse-hono-service-device-registry            ClusterIP      10.111.164.103   <none>        5671/TCP,8080/TCP,8443/TCP        36h
eclipse-hono-service-device-registry-ext        LoadBalancer   10.109.24.98     127.0.0.1     28080:31080/TCP,28443:31443/TCP   36h
eclipse-hono-service-device-registry-headless   ClusterIP      None             <none>        <none>                            36h
```

I appreciate any advise.
Thanks!

Update:

```
nano@dhcp-646 hono % java -jar hono-cli-*-exec.jar --hono.client.host=127.0.0.1 --spring.profiles.active=receiver,local --hono.client.port=15672 --hono.client.username=consumer@HONO --hono.client.password=verysecret --tenant.id=$TENANT


  ______     _ _                  _    _                   
 |  ____|   | (_)                | |  | |                  
 | |__   ___| |_ _ __  ___  ___  | |__| | ___  _ __   ___  
 |  __| / __| | | '_ \/ __|/ _ \ |  __  |/ _ \| '_ \ / _ \ 
 | |___| (__| | | |_) \__ \  __/ | |  | | (_) | | | | (_) |
 |______\___|_|_| .__/|___/\___| |_|  |_|\___/|_| |_|\___/ 
                | |                                        
                |_|                                        

Eclipse Hono Example Client  (v1.12.1)
using Spring Boot  (v2.5.9)

Go to https://www.eclipse.org/hono for more information.


12:26:58.881 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.hono.cli.Application - Starting Application v1.12.1 using Java 17.0.2 on dhcp-646.q.wlan.net.bme.hu with PID 22476 (/Users/nano/Documents/hono/hono-cli-1.12.1-exec.jar started by nano in /Users/nano/Documents/hono)
12:26:58.882 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.hono.cli.Application - The following profiles are active: receiver,local
12:26:59.122 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.hono.cli.Application - running command line client in role(s): receiver,local
12:26:59.273 [main] INFO  o.e.h.a.c.a.ProtonBasedApplicationClient - connecting to Hono endpoint
12:26:59.320 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.hono.cli.Application - Started Application in 0.744 seconds (JVM running for 1.079)
12:26:59.338 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] WARN  i.n.r.d.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders - Can not find io.netty.resolver.dns.macos.MacOSDnsServerAddressStreamProvider in the classpath, fallback to system defaults. This may result in incorrect DNS resolutions on MacOS.
12:27:10.457 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.h.client.impl.HonoConnectionImpl - max number of attempts [5] to re-connect to server [127.0.0.1:15672, role: unknown] have been made, giving up
12:27:10.465 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] ERROR org.eclipse.hono.cli.app.Receiver - Error occurred during initialization of receiver: failed to connect
```

Update: Minikube service list -n hono

| NAMESPACE | NAME | TARGET PORT | URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hono | eclipse-hono-adapter-amqp-vertx | amqp/5672 |  |
|  |  | amqps/5671 |  |
| hono | eclipse-hono-adapter-http-vertx | http/8080 |  |
|  |  | https/8443 |  |
| hono | eclipse-hono-adapter-mqtt-vertx | mqtt/1883 |  |
|  |  | secure-mqtt/8883 |  |
| hono | eclipse-hono-artemis | No node port |  |
| hono | eclipse-hono-dispatch-router | No node port |  |
| hono | eclipse-hono-dispatch-router-ext | amqps/15671 |  |
|  |  | amqp/15672 |  |
| hono | eclipse-hono-service-auth | No node port |  |
| hono | eclipse-hono-service-command-router | No node port |  |
| hono | eclipse-hono-service-device-registry | No node port |  |
| hono | eclipse-hono-service-device-registry-ext | http/28080 |  |
|  |  | https/28443 |  |
| hono | eclipse-hono-service-device-registry-headless | No node port |  |
| ----------- | ----------------------------------------------- | ------------------ | ----- |

Update:
Kubernetes services:

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   8d
```

Comment: it looks like the output of kubectl get services is garbled. Can you try to properly format it so we can get the needed information?

Comment: Fixed it. Do you need anything else?

Comment: can you try to add the following to your command line: --spring.profiles.active=receiver,local
What version of the Hono client are you using?

Comment: I added the profiles but the result was the same. I'm using hono version 1.12, same for for the cli client (1.12.1 but tried previous versions as well). I updated the question with the full command line output.

Comment: what is the output of "minikube get services" for the namespace that you have deployed Hono to?

Comment: I updated the minikube services in hono namespace.

Comment: oh sorry, I meant "kubectl get services", my bad ...

Comment: Added. Should I see the hono services exposed?

Comment: yes, but you probably simply forgot to specify the namespace ... anyways, I just saw that you had included the output in your original question.

Comment: Can you test if you are able to connect to the Hono Sandbox instead of your local minikube: java -jar hono-cli-*-exec.jar --tenant.id=DEFAULT_TENANT

Comment: Yes, it seems successfully connected to the sandbox.

Comment: and can you do the same connecting to your local cluster, i.e. using the DEFAULT_TENANT?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer,I did not have time to dig into the problem, but I did today. One thing I forgot to tell earlier that I am using arm64 architecture. As I saw, the eclipse docker hub does not contain any arm64 architecture images. Does this necessarily mean that Hono is not Arm64 compatible? I checked into my Kubernetes logs and I realised some pods were in deadlock, falling to restart over and over again.

Comment: That explains a lot. The Hono images from Docker Hub are created for AMD64, they will not run on Arm. You might be able to build the images yourself based on the general build instructions on the Hono website.